# How to install OpenCV with Visual Studio 2012 (64 bit) on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, qt, opencv, installation, windows-7-x64

I'm following this guide to install OpenCV for Qt: http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/chap1s1_2.shtml. But this tutorial is made for Qt with mingw32 compiler kit.

Kindly suggest me the steps to install it on Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 7 64bit (with or without cmake).

Comment: This might help `https://github.com/minhazul-haque/opencv-test-msvs2010`

Answer (score 0):

You need to select your compiler not MinGW.

*You then specify the compilers that will generate the project. In our case, they are the compilers of MinGW installed by default by Qt.*

You need to select 64 bit Visual Studio 11.0. And when you finish configuration and click generate button cmake is going to generate you a solution file, all you need to do is open that solution file and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this guide http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html. If you will have problems with building Qt 5.x, use Qt 4.x - it's much easier to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to solve this problem by following the guide mentioned by cyriel:http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html.

And adding following lines to myproject.pro file:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\OpenCV\build\include
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_core244.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_highgui244.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_imgproc244.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_calib3d244.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_calib3d244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_contrib244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_core244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_features2d244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_flann244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_gpu244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_highgui244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_imgproc244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_legacy244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_ml244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_nonfree244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_objdetect244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_photo244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_stitching244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_ts244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_video244d.lib
LIBS += C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib\opencv_videostab244d.lib
```

By doing this, there is no need for additional compilation again by vsc2012. It also saves hard disk space. And anyone will be able to run their opencv project written in Qt5.1.